# Meaning of topological distance between 2 pixels

Tags: image-processing, topology

I came across the notion of topology and topological distance in the context of image processing several times (especially when it came to mathematical morphology). I looked for a not too abstract explanation of "topological distance" but haven't found one yet. Can you please explain (in layaman's terms) the notion of topological distance between 2 pixels? And what's the difference between a euclidean distance and a topological distance in image-processing?

Comment: Can you give us some context, e.g., a citation to the source where you saw the phrase used and the surrounding context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Nonlinear Signal and Image Processing: Theory, Methods, and Applications* defines topological distance as follows. First, you have to define when two pixels are *neighbors*. The book offers two possibilities:

- The neighbors of a pixel are the 4 "cardinal" pixels around it.
- The neighbors of a pixel are the 8 pixels surrounding it.

This defines a graph (two pixels are connected by an edge if they are neighbors). The *topological distance* between two pixels $p,q$ is then the graph distance between $p$ and $q$.

The first choice above corresponds to $L^1$ ("Manhattan") distance, and the second choice to $L^\infty$ distance. This contrasts with the usual $L^2$ (Euclidean) distance.